# DataVisualization - empty function bodies in ILSpy

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I'm doing some astrophysics research and I'm analysing data using Win-Form Chart component. On X-Axis is date and on Y-Axis is value, and I'm applying MovingAverage using member method `DataManipulator.FinancialFormula` of Chart on values.

I and my advisor are concerned how this function handles missing dates. So I tried to look with `ILSpy` into `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll` to see how it's implemented but I found all function bodies empty but when I examined `TcpClient` `Dispose` and `Close` methods, I was able to see full function bodies. I have tried `ILDasm` and `JustDecompile` with same results as `ILSpy`.

Why are method bodies from `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll` empty?

So where the real code of `DataManipulator.FinancialFormula` is located?

Or how this function handles gaps in dates?

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: I can see the method implementation in ILSpy. The `FinancialFormula` method is in `DataFormula` class which is derived by `DataManipulator`.

Comment: @Junaith I can see function too, but function body is empty for me. When I select DataFormula.FinancialFormula, I can only see this: http://pastebin.com/bpCubq4v

Comment: @Rfilip - See the ILSpy screenshot http://i.imgur.com/5aHVAwL.jpg You can see the implementation

Comment: @Junaith Ok. Strange. Maybe I'm looking into wrong file - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll" Is this path correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between my and @Junaith output from ILSpy lead me to tought that I'm looking at wrong file -`C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Windows.‌​Forms.DataVisualization.dll`. This path I obtained from comment at top of metadata of  `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataFormula` viewed by using "Go to Definition" VS function on member method DataManipulator.FinancialFormula of Chart.

So I ran my program and with [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/cs-cz/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) I looked on loaded .NET Assemblies in properties of my program process. For my surprise the dll mentioned before wasn't even there, instead I found there `C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Wind0de890be#\a4711c664a774896b35428b1a3bf9470\System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.ni.dll`.

I loaded that dll into ILSpy and methods have full implementation including their bodies.

Comment: It occurs that `ILSpy` can open assemblies directly from GAC: File -> Open from GAC. I had the same problem of empty function bodies in System.Data.dll.